implicit function theorem to determine minimum of a function
Consider a function $F(x,y)$.
We are given the following assumptions, for $y_0 < y_1$:

convexity: $$\partial^2 F(x,y) / \partial y^2 > 0$$
initially decreasing: $$\partial F(x,y)/\partial y \vert_{y=y_0}<0$$
finally increasing: $$\partial F(x,y)/\partial y \vert_{y=y_1}>0$$

Based on the above, can we conclude that there exists $y^\star(x) \in (y_0, y_1)$ such that  the following two properties hold?

Existence of critical point:
$$\partial F(x,y)/\partial y \vert_{y=y^\star}=0$$

For $y>y^\star$, $$\partial F(x,y)/\partial y >0$$


Alternatively, could we use the implicit function theorem to show that given the above three conditions, there exists $y^\star(x) \in (y_0, y_1)$ such that  the above two properties hold?
I thought about the following argument, but I'm not sure if it is needed or if it is correct:
$$G(x,y)=\partial F(x,y)/\partial y =0$$
Given assumption 1), it follows from the implicit function theorem that there exists $y^\star(x)$ such that
$$G(x,y^\star(x))=0$$
Now, is it obvious from the assumptions that $y^\star(x) \in (y_0, y_1)$?
